# Removing files off a dead computer (HD doesn't fit Sharkoon adapter)

Tags: hard-drive

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me figure out what to do. I've been asked to get some files off a friend's computer that won't turn on. I'm no expert by any means, but I'm fresh off the high of saving some files from another friend's computer that wouldn't turn on (fan issue). I've removed the HD and used a Sharkoon QuickPort Combo (like this https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JMMEkBCVdik/maxresdefault.jpg) to make it function as an external drive and I'm trying to do the same with this one, but I've run into a bit of a problem.

I realise that it is recommended that an expert handle this for important things, but I was asked to do it as a favour as they're not keen to pay an expert to do it.

The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite A60 with a HD labeled 2004. I've got it out okay, but the prongs are completely different to what will fit in the Sharkoon - http://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/1ZQAAOxy9MpSOlos/s-l200.jpg

I've used the Sharkoon precisely twice, so I'm not sure if there is some adapter that I should be getting to let the A60 HD fit...or whether there is another way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: HDD from the Thoshiba is likely an IDE model while your Sharkoon uses SATA.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Seth. Do you think something like this would work? http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/44-pin-2-5-IDE-HDD-SSD-Laptop-Hard-Drive-Female-to-7-15-pin-Male-SATA-Adapter-/322234195842

Comment: This will probably make the IDE-connector too big to fit into the Sharkoon QuickPort Combo. I think it would make more sense to buy a usb-to-ide adapter like this one (http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-to-IDE-SATA-2-5-3-5-Hard-Disk-HDD-Cable-Converter-LW-/182286297918?epid=1049406354&hash=item2a711c2b3e:g:31oAAOSw8gVX34kh). Note: This is just the first hit for usb ide adapter, I didn't check the product in detail. Make sure whatever you buy has the right IDE and power connector. Also transfer via USB2.0 will probably be very slow, especially with a cheap adapter.